# Zoom to bounding box without topoJSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

The Mike Bostock 'Zoom to bounding box' example presumes that you are using topoJSON.

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541

How can the script be amended so that you can also use it with geoJSON data? Specifically, my script wouldn't use the following:

```
.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
```

but something like this:

```
.data(collection.features)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block actually already uses geojson - a d3 geoPath doesn't draw topojson objects, it draws geojson objects:

> #### path(object[, arguments…]) <>
>
> Renders the given object, which may be any GeoJSON feature or geometry
>   object
>
> ... ([link](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#geoPath))

Let's take a look at your example:

```
.data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features)
```

`topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states)` returns a feature collection, a geojson feature collection.

`.features` access the features of the feature collection (an array of polygons in this case).

What is being fed to `.data()` *is* already geojson. So we can just use `.data(geojson.features)` as you suggest (if we have a feature collection, otherwise we can just an array of geojson objects).

We can demonstrate that with your example two ways - preconvert your data to geojson with topojson in browser [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4699541), or we can load a geojson file and drop the conversion from topojson altogether, as seen [here](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/53de779aebbb9d3dd2c13435b5e1ed36).

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Extremely helpful.